# Aggregate shared values into a new column

Tags: aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate the values for several rows into a new column. Specifically, I'm looking to sum Conflict_Events for the same Year_Week and Country into a new column Conflicts_Week. For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5zUT.png)

So Afghanistan's event count (Conflicts_Week) for 1989_4 would be 11. Armenia's for 1989_2 would be 3. I found something similar on stack, but it only matches using one variable instead of two: aggregate(x = df$Conflict_Events, by = list(df$Year_Week), FUN = sum). How would I include an additional variable, so that it matches on Country as well?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just got it.

aggregate(x = ucdp$best, by = list(ucdp$Year_Week, ucdp$country), FUN = sum)